# Firebase Functions: store lang constants

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it good idea to store languages constants in `index.js`? This constants are using for push notifications.

Also, may be there is a suitable format for lang constants? Thanks.

```
const stringPushSomethingNew = "pushSomethingNew";
const stringPushTwoStuffAnd = "pushTwoStuffAnd";
const stringPushRentsSells = "pushRentsSells";
const stringPushRents = "pushRents";
const stringPushSells = "pushSells";

var mapStringsEn = new Object();
mapStringsEn[stringPushSomethingNew] = "Something new";
mapStringsEn[stringPushTwoStuffAnd] = "and";
mapStringsEn[stringPushRentsSells] = "rents out and sells";
mapStringsEn[stringPushRents] = "rents out";
mapStringsEn[stringPushSells] = "sells";

mapStringsEn["2000"] = "Gadget";
mapStringsEn["2001"] = "Mobile phone";
mapStringsEn["2002"] = "Smartphone";
mapStringsEn["2003"] = "Tablet";
```